# (Can we) Determine the slope of the line from single points from parallel lines?

Tags: geometry

This is a very elementary question that I am missing out,

So, given two (or more) points in parallel lines, (i.e. we only know of a single point lying in each line), (can we) determine the slope of the line?

Comment: If you have two different points on the same line then yes, of course you can know the line's slope. If you have two points on *different* lines then you can not.

Comment: i am not sure if it is possible, but never hurts to double check!

Comment: I've no idea what you mean...

Comment: Is it possible to find the slope of *what* line?

Comment: Now @AndréNicolas has made it clear the OP could have meant yet *another* thing...This usually happens with poorly worded questions.

Comment: the slope of the 'parallel lines' on which the points lie
(i am sorry if it was not clear earlier)

Comment: @DonAntonio sorry about my first comment.. it was supposed to be placed right under the question, and was not meant as a reply to your comment :)

Comment: @user1697693, I'm convinced my first comment fully answers your question, and probably others as well.

Comment: yeah.. i agree.. as i replied in the answer below, this is my understanding too.. however I was just double checking if I am missing out something.. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2 points on a line to get the slope and/or equation for the line, if you only have 1 point for each line, then it is not possible to get the slope since there will be infinite number of lines passing that point with different slopes.

Comment: thanks.. that is my understanding too.. as I said a pretty trivial question, right :)

Comment: Yes, you are right!@user1697693